# how to create spreadsheets for ipad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, spreadsheet

i want a spreadsheet to be created in my application . i have searched many forums but i cant get exact solution to move forward. can any one help me out in creating it for my proj which looks similar to numbers spreadsheet app for ipad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create html for spreadsheet  and show in webview

Comment: i am developing a native application with some hard coded data in it, i need to make use of the existing data and make a spreadsheet. pls guide me in achieving this

Comment: please can you send me a screenshot of your view so i can better understand what's you actully need

Comment: is there any other possibilities other than loading in the webview i mean customization of tableview.